# Best way to paint plastic chrome sink fittings?

Tags: painting, bathroom-fixtures

I've just installed a matte black faucet and would like the drain and overflow covers, which are currently chrome, to match. (See first picture.) The fittings are plastic. They should be easy enough to paint, but I'd like to make sure they'll look nice and match the faucet because it won't be easy to find a replacement drain cover if I mess it up.

I've found some online instructions for painting chromed *metal* bathroom parts ([here](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/how-to-paint-chrome/) and [here](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/refinish-chrome-bathroom-fixtures-50591.html)), and there are special paints/kits for painting chromed plastic on cars (e.g. PlastiDip), but I suspect that's overkill.

Can I just spray these parts with matte black paint? Do I need to sand and prime them first, as with chromed metal?

thanks

PS - If you're wondering why I don't just buy matte black parts:

I can buy a matte black overflow cover, but can't find a matte black drain cover that works with the installed assembly. The drain is from Ikea and designed to be "shallow" (i.e. immediate 90 degree bend to horizontal) in order to accommodate large drawers in a floating vanity. (See second picture.) The matte black drain covers I'm finding come as part of vertical drain assemblies and won't fit the Ikea drain/threadings.

[image: image 1 - black matte faucet and chrome fittings]
[image: image 2 - "shallow" Ikea sink drain assembly]

Comment: PlastiDip may be the way to go, especially since it does work on plastichrome. I'd check on its waterproof capabilities, though. You would, most likely, need to rough up the surface to get it to stick. I sprayed PlastiDip on a chromed tool handle (metal, not plastic) - looked _fantastic_! Until I used it once and most of it came off... :(

Comment: Would imagine a decent sanding will be a must do.  Paint almost always needs some surface to hold onto.

Comment: Also: [Darth Vader, your faucet has arrived](https://www.backissues.com/cgi-bin/backissues.cgi?full/CD198705.JPG).

Comment: @FreeMan I assumed PlastiDip is waterproof and durable, given its use on car exteriors. Your experience suggests otherwise... Also: I actually preferred [the faucet that my girlfriend says looks like a spaceship](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Single-Hole-Single-Handle-Lavatory-Faucet-in-Black-Finish-YPG323-BK/308706319). This one strikes me as more [steampunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steampunk), but I've taken to calling it [Mrs. Potts](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Mrs._Potts).

Comment: I've seen PlastiDipped wheels, and they survived nicely. It may have had something to do with my (total lack of) preparation work...

Answer (score 1):

Don't paint these parts. The paint will flake off and it will look awful. Just accept that they don't match. *Matching* is *such* a cliche!

Comment: But it won't _hurt_ anything...

Comment: @Jim My girlfriend agrees with you, and I worry about flaking, so they may indeed just stay that way.